# Programmatically Adding An Attribute

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add attribute from the setup script.Even though attribute is getting added,some of the options has different values than the one specified in the setup script

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();


$entityTypeId = 'catalog_product';
$attributeCode ='dz_video';

$data = array(
    'type'=>'textarea',
    'input'=>'text',
    'label'=>'Video',
    'is_required' =>'0',
    'is_unique' =>'0',
    'is_global' =>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'is_comparable'=>'0',
    'is_wysiwyg_enabled'=>'0',
    'is_searchable'=>'0',
    'is_used_for_price_rules'=>'0',
    'is_html_allowed_on_front'=>'1',
    'is_visible_on_front'=>'1',
    'used_in_product_listing'=>'0',
    'used_for_sort_by'=>'0',
    'user_defined'=>'1',
    'is_configurable'=>'1'
);

$installer->addAttribute($entityTypeId,$attributeCode,$data);
```

For example,specified value for 'is_required' is 0 but in the admin "Required" option is set to Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a somewhat weird behavior in the EAV setup class. When you use addAttribute, then your data array is remapped. This is not the case in updateAttribute. Check the class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup and its _prepareValues() method.
For example your is_required needs to be simply "required" to work as expected!

Answer (score 2):

mpaepper's answer is correct. Also in some cases rather than 1 or 0, the value needs to be true or false. E.g:

```
'required' => false,
```